# delete and tar files based on the date in the filename

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I need help on to archiving the below files on the date in the file name.Also I want to delete the archive after 100 days. For example, I have tried to archive all the csv...2018, keeping the archive for 100 days. I have tried to delete

```
AUSDUVZRO1Y_pm00hr_20180309.000005_6.csv
KYXMNCDTO6Y_pm00hr_20180309.040006_10.csv

example: 
 11randomletters_6randomalphanumeric_YYYYMMDD.randomnumbers_randomnum.csv
```

I have tried the following sample and it is not working. Can someone help me on fixing this?

```
    #!/bin/bash
DEST_DIR=/tmp/arc/
OLD_FILES=$(date --date="30 days ago" +%s)
    echo "$(date -u) START OF ARCHIVE SCRIPT "  >> "${LOGS}"
        for files in /tmp/archive/*.csv; do
        DIFF=$(date --d="$(echo "$files" | cut -d_ -f3 | cut -d. -f1)" +%s)
        if [ "$DIFF" -lt "$OLD_FILES" ]; then
        tar --create --gzip --file="$DEST_DIR$files -P $SRC_DIR"
        fi
        done
```

Summary: For example today date is 27 March 2018. I want to archive all the files csv files received on 20th March 2018. Also keeping this archive for 100 days and delete the archive every day which is 100 days older.
Note: File needs to be archived based on the date in the file name, without using `find mtime +30 days`.

I couldn't help myself to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to put archives and csvs that you want to archive and keep 100 days under `tmp`. Find another place for that. I assume, that the variable `topdir` will be your new top directory.

For the rest, just do as you said you want it to work.

```
date_to_archive=$(date  --date="7 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')
date_to_del=$(date --date="100 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')

#I want to archive all the files csv files received on 20th March 2018
tar cvzf "$topdir"/arc/$date_to_archive.tgz "$topdir"/archive/*_$date_to_archive.*.csv

#delete the archive every day which is 100 days old
rm "$topdir"/arc/$date_to_del.tgz
```

If you run this every day in cron

```
   23    23  *   *   *  /bin/bash /where/the/script/is
```

would that not do what you want?